# Getting started with strings in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function that takes a string of gggggggeeeeetttttt and can count how many times the letter repeats and output as g7e5t6.

I've only just started Haskell so not really sure at all where to start.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Very harsh.You actually can't upvote until you get 15 rep.  Welcome to the site

Comment: @amccausl: Sorry. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 13):

The function `group` will group together identical elements in a list. Since a string is a list of characters, we have:

```
group "ggggeeetttt" = ["gggg","eee","tttt"]
```

To get the letter, we can use `map head`, since `head` takes the first element of a string (or any list):

```
map head ["gggg","eee","tttt"] = ['g','e','t']
```

Now, we want to know how many elements there are in each substring. This can be done using `map length`:

```
map length ["gggg","eee","tttt"] = [4,3,4]
```

Let's turn these numbers back into strings:

```
map show [4,3,4] = ["4","3","4"]
```

Now we need to combine the original list and length list somehow. We can do this as follows:

```
zipWith (:) ['g','e','t'] ["4","3","4"]
```

`zipWith` will apply the specified function to paired elements in the two lists. Here I've used `(:)`, which adds an element to the start of the list.

This gives you all the building blocks you need to do what you want. For example, this should work, although I haven't tested it:

```
f s = concat $ zipWith (:) letters lengths
    where
        groups  = group s
        letters = map head groups
        lengths = map (show . length) groups
```

Comment: I should say also that you need to import Data.List to get some of these list manipulating functions

Comment: Nice answer.  I would have liked it better if you had left off the final "summary" and let the OP put that together himself.

Comment: Yes, I debated whether to put it there or not. Maybe it would have been better without.

Comment: On a slightly different topic, Eric, do you understand the use of (.), ($) and concat? I realise I didn't define those before using them in the function that I posted.

Answer (score 7):

Variant with comprehensions, imo a bit prettier (considering previous explanations just code):

```
ghci> let s = "gggggggeeeeetttttt"
ghci> putStrLn $ concat [head g: show (length g) | g <- group s]
g7e5t6
```

Comment: He asked how to get started, not how to read a refined solution off a site.  This is likely to be homework, and your answer is likely to be a valid answer to the homework problem.  Not helpful.

Comment: @luqui: Everything here except comprehensions was explained earlier. And I think it's pretty easy to read and play with in ghci to understand pieces even if it is actually a homework. So as auxiliary answer it can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to start, is to figure out your problem. I would suggest the following method:

1. Split the string into substrings of equal characters. So, you need a function which takes a `String` and returns, a list of strings (`[String]`).
   Example: `splitStr "gggggggeeeeetttttt"` should return `["ggggggg","eeeee","tttttt"]`
   Happily, the module `Data.List` already provides such a function, it's named `group`.
2. Calculate the number of repetitions and the letter which is repeated. The number of repetition is simply the length of the sublist, use `length` for that.
3. Get the repeated character and stick it in front of the number of repetitions. For the repeated character, we may use any one of the list, we take the first one. To calculate the first element of a list (aka string), you can use `head`. Eg. `head "abc"` yields `'a'`.
   To stick this in front of the length, you can use a small helper function and `show`, which turns most stuff into a string. Our helper looks like this: `makeRepetitions string = head string : show (length string)`. `:` aka cons adds an element to the front of a list.
4. Apply the helper of step (3) to all elements of the list of string in (1). We use `map` for that. `map` applies a function to a list of values and returns the list of results
5. concat the sublists together to your result. We can use `concat` for this. Actually, we can combine (4) and (5) using `concatMap`. This function maps a function to a list of values and concats the results - just as we want it.

Now, your code looks like this:

```
import Data.List

runlength :: String -> String
runlength string = concatMap makeRepetitions (group string)) where
  makeRepetitions string = head string : show (length string)
```

Because that much brackets are annoying, Haskellers often use `.`.The dot combines two functions to create a  new one. You can think of `f = functionA . functionB` is equal to `f x = functionA (functionB x)`. Using the dot, we can reformat the program a bit:

```
import Data.List

runlength :: String -> String
runlength = concatMap makeRepetitions . group where
  makeRepetitions string = head string : show (length string)
```

IMO, This representation is more readable. You can see `runlength` as a pipeline. First apply `group`, then we use `concatMap` to map `makeRepetitions` onto the input and concat the results.

Comment: Again, great answer if you hadn't put it all together for him at the end.  I'd have cut it off after point (5).

Answer (score 1):

Abuse of arrows and pointfree :)

```
f = group >>> concatMap (head &&& (show . length) >>> uncurry (:))
```

And here's with applicative:

```
f = concatMap ((:) <$> head <*> (show . length)) . group
```

Comment: I know you are just playing, but writing a function that does the task in a dense opaque way is not helpful to a beginner, especially if it is likely to be homework.

Comment: I did say it was an abuse. Why the downvote ? It's good to show the bad practices and clearly define them as bad.